# DAX more efficient way to get exchange rate data

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm struggling with a difficult problem about calculate exchange rates. I've two tables, the first one has data about date, currency and exchange rates, the second one has data about date, currency, value in local currency. I can't use RELATED funtion, because I can connect my data only by many to many relationship, so I wanted to use LOOKUPVALUE.

My code is below:

```
LOOKUPVALUE('ExchangeRates'[ExchangeRate],
    'ExchangeRates'[Currency],Data[Currency],
    'ExchangeRates'[Date],
        LASTDATE(
            FILTER(
                ALL('ExchangeRates'[Date]),
                'ExchangeRates'[Date] <= Data[Date])
        )
)
```

Yes, It works, but LOOKUPVALUE is heavy and very bad for the report'perfomance. Do you know better solutions? I have heard something about TREATAS, but TREATAS is also a performance killer for large amount of data (about 12kk rows)

Best Regards

Comment: Hello Michal. Please check this article. https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/currency-conversion-in-power-bi-reports/

Comment: Did you try LASTNONBLANK() for currency date? smth like LASTNONBLANK(Data[Date],COUNTROWS(RELATEDTABLE('ExchangeRates'))), then calculate()/Calculatetable(). And may be it's better to use a report measure instead of calcColumn.